# How could I extract data only for end of month dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[How could I use a function (VLOOKUP?) to only consider the last transaction for each month (Column C) and record it in Column F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItPIB.png)

[I have tried variations of =VLOOKUP(EDATE(E5, 0),B5:C19, 2), but it results in:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIYCA.png)

I have a feeling the EDATE function is not correctly identifying the final transaction of each month to feed that date into VLOOKUP. TYIA!

Comment: sumif() may work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS($B$4:$B$18,$B$4:$B$18,"<"&E4),$B$4:$C$18,2,0)

Comment: When I try this I get incorrect results. I think your `E4` should be changed to `EOMONTH(E4)`, as eg specifying `E4` as just `Jul-18` actually puts the date of `01-Jul-18` into the cell. Of course, you may actually have put (or assumed) end of month dates into range `E4:E18`, in which case your solution will work.

Comment: Just to add to your solution, if you added an additional condition to your `MAXIFS` that `$B$4:$B$18` is greater than or equal to the first day of the month containing date in `E4` then this will deliver `#N/A` in those months where the month (in `E4:E12`) does not appear in `B4:B18` - the case for Apr-18 and Jan-18. Trapping this error with `IFERROR` would allow the "-" character to  be displayed in the results as indicated in the OP.

Comment: Thank you for these responses! I did find that modifying the condition from "greater than" to "greater than or equal to" allowed the VLOOKUP to include additional dates that did not end on the last day of the month.

=VLOOKUP(MAXIFS($B$5:$B$21,$B$5:$B$21,"<="&E5),$B$5:$C$21,2,0)